# Euro Symbol in Python pdfkit

Tags: python, pdfkit

How can i render the Euro Symbol (€) using Python pdfkit?

```
... <div class='col-50 left pleft'> € 15.50 </div> ....
```

using just this render to `â‚¬`, tested with different font.

Im using `pdfkit.from_string` function

Comment: Sounds like the input HTML is malformed.  Have you declared its character set as UTF-8 (which it looks like pdfkit is receiving, only interpreting as Latin-1) within the HTML tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using html version of Euro Symbol `&euro;`

Answer (score -1):

Try this '\u20AC' instead of '€'

Comment: This is correct for strings in Python, but the OP's example is HTML.